# IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults not behaving as thought

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I have this simple test project just to test the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults behavior.

```
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("test");
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
    }
```

In the app.config of the service i have it set to true

```
 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
```

On the client side:

```
            try
            {
                using (var proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
                    Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData(5));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

This is what I thought the behavior was:
Setting to includeExceptionDetailInFaults=true would propagate the exception detail to the client. But I'm always getting the CommunicationObjectFaultException.

I did try having the FaultContract(typeof(InvalidCastException)) on the contract but same behavior, only getting the CommunicationObjectFaultException.

The only way to make it work was to throw new FaultException(new InvalidCastException("test"));

But I thought with IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true the above was done automatically.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you've put the service client inside a `using` block.

WCF clients are the one place in .NET where you [shouldn't use `using`](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/03/WCF-Dispose), because it will mask the "real" exception.

Technical explanation: `Dispose` calls `Close`, which will always throw a `CommunicationObjectFaultedException` if the channel is already faulted (i.e. as a result of a previous exception), which subsequently puts *that* exception at the top of the stack.  When cleaning up an `ICommunicationObject`, in order to avoid masking the exception, you have to first check the `State` to see if it is faulted, and if so call `Abort` instead of `Close`.

Comment: ah thanks! what does Close do to cause a communicationobjectfaultexception when the channel is faulted?

Comment: @pdiddy: `CommunicationObject.Close` is literally programmed to throw an exception if the channel is faulted.  It's not accidental.

Comment: Couldn't it check for the state and abort when the channel is faulted?  Just wondering why it's implemented that way.

Comment: @pdiddy: It does check the state, and it does call `Abort`... and then it throws an exception.  I'm sure that it *could* do many other things, but that's the way the WCF team chose to implement it, to the detriment of many. It's even documented on MSDN now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733912.aspx